# Include multiple plugins in a single Typoscript Object Path

Tags: typo3, typoscript

If I have an element in my Templavoila template which is a a Typoscript Object Path, is it possible to include more than one plugin through typoscript?

I have tried the following but it does not render anything.

`lib.my_mapping.10 < plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1`

`lib.my_mapping.20 < plugin.tx_myotherplugin_pi1`

If I want to just render a single plugin then it works fine e.g

`lib.my_mapping.10 < plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need first declare `lib.my_mapping` as `COA` cObject (`COA` stands for [Content Object Array](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/COA))

```
lib.my_mapping = COA
lib.my_mapping {
  10 < plugin.tx_some_pi1
  20 < plugin.tx_some_pi2
  // etc
}
```